# Rails ERB Inside Javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, erb

I'm trying to use some *View* instance variables inside *Javascript*.

My *JS* file is included in the *head* tag of my *HTML*. And it's a **.js* file in *assets/javascript*.

When I try to...

```
console.log(<%= @some_instance_variable %>)
```

... I get syntax error. And if I try to...

```
console.log('<%= @some_instance_variable %>')
```

... the output is just the string *<%= @some_instance_variable %>*. How can I do to obtain the instance variable's actual value?. I'd really appreciate any help!.

Regards!.

Comment: You have to make it an erb file. I'd argue against doing so, though.

Comment: I've tried to add the *js.erb* suffix but then the include doesn't work. Any clue?. Or any other option?.

Comment: Do you really need to include it in `<head>`? What's the problem with `require_tree .` in application.js?

Comment: It's a page specific *JS*. With **require_tree .** it will include it in every view, it's an overhead I don't want. I could add the *javascript_include_tag* in the body, but does it make any difference?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include it with:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag('file_name.js.erb'.sub('.erb', '')) %>
```

But in fact it's a very ugly solution. If you want to use rails variables in JS scripts, use [gon gem](https://github.com/gazay/gon).